# Ubuntu 16.04 Slow booting

Tags: boot

I'm experiencing very slow bootup times, ~2-3 minutes. I've searched the forums and attempted several fixes (it's been a few weeks and I don't remember exactly.) From looking at dmesg output it looks like it's attempting to connect to wifi but can't make a connection, however once logged in the internet connects instantly.

EDIT:

`systemd-analyze` outputs:

```
Startup finished in 8.200s (kernel) + 3min 388ms (userspace) = 3min 8.588s
```

and `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20:`

```
 7.602s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
           642ms lvm2-monitor.service
           491ms dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
           244ms ModemManager.service
           235ms apparmor.service
           199ms accounts-daemon.service
           172ms plymouth-read-write.service
           163ms snapd.firstboot.service
           162ms systemd-logind.service
           148ms speech-dispatcher.service
           142ms grub-common.service
           135ms irqbalance.service
           134ms ondemand.service
           132ms apport.service
           120ms upower.service
           102ms rsyslog.service
            98ms console-setup.service
            97ms systemd-localed.service
            94ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            92ms minidlna.service
```

Here's the result of `dmesg`:

```
[    1.686111] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[    1.686136] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.686163] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.686166] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.686202] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.712197] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2594.111 MHz
[    1.712201] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2564811980e, max_idle_ns: 440795290434 ns
[    1.716657]  sda: sda1
[    1.717088] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.846654] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5470], y [..4498]
[    1.924184] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd047b3/0xb40000/0xa0000/0x0, board id: 0, fw id: 920262
[    1.924191] psmouse serio1: synaptics: serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
[    1.940250] usb 2-1.5.4: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    1.963732] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[    2.004256] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    2.007119] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:1f:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[    2.007499] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:02:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[    2.007506] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[    2.008621] ata2.00: ATAPI: MATSHITADVD-RAM UJ8C2, SB01, max UDMA/133
[    2.011435] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:1f:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[    2.011828] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:02:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[    2.011836] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[    2.012947] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.022020] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8C2    SB01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.039739] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.039742] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.039925] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.040045] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    2.057614] usb 2-1.5.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0a81, idProduct=0205
[    2.057621] usb 2-1.5.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.057625] usb 2-1.5.4: Product: PS2 to USB Converter
[    2.057628] usb 2-1.5.4: Manufacturer: CHESEN
[    2.064650] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.077551] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.077552] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.078831] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5.4/2-1.5.4:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/input/input7
[    2.096423] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.096592] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 200x56
[    2.096638] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.096803] ACPI: Video Device [VID] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    2.097755] acpi device:00: registered as cooling_device4
[    2.097812] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8
[    2.132540] hid-generic 0003:0A81:0205.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5.4/input0
[    2.132640] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20151010 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    2.132770] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5.4/2-1.5.4:1.1/0003:0A81:0205.0002/input/input9
[    2.136209] usb 2-1.5.6: new low-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[    2.188600] hid-generic 0003:0A81:0205.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5.4/input1
[    2.232314] usb 2-1.5.6: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c06a
[    2.232318] usb 2-1.5.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.232319] usb 2-1.5.6: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    2.232321] usb 2-1.5.6: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.234501] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5.6/2-1.5.6:1.0/0003:046D:C06A.0003/input/input10
[    2.234618] hid-generic 0003:046D:C06A.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5.6/input0
[    2.360246] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    2.363244] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    2.363248] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    2.363251] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[    2.363445] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    2.363539] ata3.00: ATA-9: LITEONIT LMH-256V2M-41 MSATA 256GB SED, 3M8410D, max UDMA/133
[    2.363541] ata3.00: 500118192 sectors, multi 2: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.364054] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    2.364057] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    2.364059] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[    2.364250] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    2.364437] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.364690] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      LITEONIT LMH-256 10D  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.364925] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 500118192 512-byte logical blocks: (256 GB/238 GiB)
[    2.364955] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    2.365022] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    2.365025] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.365042] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.365513]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 < sdb5 >
[    2.365896] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.684238] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.691860] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[    2.691879] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
[    2.712274] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    6.178760] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    6.378518] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input6
[    8.179626] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.272448] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[    8.272548] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    8.272688] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <cameron-T430s>.
[    8.315655] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    8.361740] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[    8.361794] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    8.361815] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    8.361841] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    8.361856] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    8.361874] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    8.361881] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    8.361887] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    8.361893] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[    8.361917] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    8.361942] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[    8.362008] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    8.376285] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    8.376705] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[    8.377106] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    8.377226] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    8.377282] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[    8.377608] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[    8.377960] systemd[1]: Starting Set console keymap...
[    8.378827] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    8.378903] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    8.378963] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    8.379044] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    8.379059] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    8.380246] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    8.380420] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    8.383487] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    8.383509] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    8.383911] systemd[1]: Started Braille Device Support.
[    8.384129] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    8.384662] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    8.388334] systemd[1]: Started Read required files in advance.
[    8.389523] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    8.389658] systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
[    8.393137] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    8.393175] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    8.393194] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    8.411878] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    8.413396] systemd[1]: Started LVM2 metadata daemon.
[    8.413936] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    8.420923] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    8.427233] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    8.427817] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    8.428342] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    8.431127] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    8.439223] systemd[1]: Started Set console keymap.
[    8.440617] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    8.541822] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    8.551251] systemd-journald[280]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    8.648223] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    8.675975] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.PMIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
[    8.675982] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    8.675998] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
[    8.676001] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    8.676003] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
[    8.676006] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    8.676007] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
[    8.676011] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    8.676012] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    8.688747] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    8.697339] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.25
[    8.697342] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[    8.697344] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS G7ETA4WW (2.64 ), EC unknown
[    8.697345] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad T430s, model 2356AB4
[    8.697813] thinkpad_acpi: detected a 16-level brightness capable ThinkPad
[    8.697918] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are enabled
[    8.697935] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[    8.697937] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[    8.702623] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is blocked
[    8.703374] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading native one
[    8.707344] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input11
[    8.710435] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    8.727784] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    8.738361] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    8.738363] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[    8.738519] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    8.747257] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC269VC: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.747262] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.747265] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=2 (0x15/0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.747266] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.747268] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    8.747271] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x18
[    8.747273] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Dock Mic=0x19
[    8.747275] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    8.747579] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.748617] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-5.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.754003] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 9.221.4.1 build 25532 op_mode iwldvm
[    8.762351] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b2db)
[    8.764211] input: Integrated Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input16
[    8.764387] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    8.764389] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    8.769066] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[    8.769140] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[    8.769244] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[    8.769327] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[    8.769400] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input17
[    8.769466] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input18
[    8.769534] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input19
[    8.792916] AVX version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    8.792919] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    8.795342] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    8.795345] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[    8.795346] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[    8.795348] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN, REV=0x74
[    8.800096] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    8.857962] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[    8.905984] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    8.905987] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    8.905989] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    8.905994] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[    8.910939] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    8.910942] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    8.910944] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    8.910947] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.910949] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.910951] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.910953] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.910956] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    8.910958] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    8.910959] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.910961] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.911651] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    9.187903] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[    9.192311] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[    9.301560] Adding 8077308k swap on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8077308k SSFS
[    9.360861] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.779:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=722 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.360869] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.779:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=722 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.360874] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.779:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=722 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.360878] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.779:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=722 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.362252] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.779:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=726 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.362260] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.779:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=726 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.365149] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.783:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=727 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.366425] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.783:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app" pid=725 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.366430] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.783:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app//oxide_helper" pid=725 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.367213] audit: type=1400 audit(1477072973.783:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=729 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   98.971467] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   98.971664] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   98.978333] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   98.978422] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[   99.199479] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   99.206214] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   99.206317] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[   99.299548] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   99.303584] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   99.538103] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   99.686781] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  118.114297] wlp3s0: authenticate with 48:5d:36:54:79:98
[  118.161796] wlp3s0: send auth to 48:5d:36:54:79:98 (try 1/3)
[  118.163624] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  118.166210] wlp3s0: associate with 48:5d:36:54:79:98 (try 1/3)
[  118.169868] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 48:5d:36:54:79:98 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  118.175258] wlp3s0: associated
[  118.175300] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[  118.178469] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[  118.178474] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC
[  118.178475] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  118.178478] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[  118.178481] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
[  118.178483] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
[  118.178485] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
[  118.178487] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[  118.178489] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
`
```

Comment: I don't think I can help you directly with this issue, but the output of `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20` could maybe be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I added the outputs to those commands in the thread. Not sure what to make of them, though...

Comment: Maybe add some info about your wireless card hardware and what driver is in use, you might get improvements by installing a different driver. That's totally not my field of experience though.